# menu mouseenter mouseleave click

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Anyone can help me? I want a dropdown menu with animation on mouseenter and mouseleave events but when clicked after mouse enter I want the submenu stay visible until new click anywhere in page (in the example is only in the body). After that second click (same animation of mouseleave) I want mouseenter and mouseleave .on again like when we started.

```
$('#menu > li').on('mouseenter',function(){
    //mouseenter handler
});

$('#menu > li').on('mouseleave',function(){
    //mouseleave handler
});
$('#menu > li').toggle(
  function () {
  $('#menu > li').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  },
  function () {
  //mouseleave handler
  });
$('body').click(function(){
  //same mouseleave handler
});
```

I don't know how i can enable mouseenter/mouseleave after second click. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: Hi Jose, welcome to Stack Overflow. What problem are you having with this code?

Comment: Hi Frank! This code hasn't any problem... it works, but I want something different. I wanted an animated hover menu (mouseenter and mouseleave) and if i click in the menu when submenu is visible i want submenu stay visible and disable mouseenter and mouseleave. And enable mouseenter/mouseleave again when click anywhere in the Body.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that José. But what is keeping you from building that? Or are you asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: I'm trying Frank but i'mo not achieving that. Maybe tomorrow. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

This could be significantly simplified using event delegation:

```
$('document').on("click",'#menu > li', function() {
    $('#menu > li').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
});

$('document').on("click",':not(#menu > li)', function() {
    $('#menu > li').on('mouseenter', function(){
         //your mouseenter handler goes here
    });
    $('#menu > li').on('mouseleave', function(){
         //your mouseleave handler goes here
    });
});
```

This is semantically equivalent to:

```
If a click happens on a menu item, unbind mouse enter/leave events

If a click happens on a non menu item, bind mouse enter/leave events
```

Comment: I like it, although OP specified that a second click on the menu should re-enable the mouse motion handlers.