# Event delegation to support hover and click on acordian menu

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am building a vertical accordion navigation that requires that the sub-nav links are presented and remain open on hover or click of .accordionButton.

So far I have been able to get the child .accordionContent to expand when hovered, however it does not remain open.

I saw this SO page: [menu mouseenter mouseleave click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585867/menu-mouseenter-mouseleave-click), which may be a good start but cannot wrap my head around the implimentation.

Here are my fiddle and markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/faGMR/8/

## HTML

```
<ul id="mainNav">
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 1</a>

    <ul class="accordionContent">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">sub link 1</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">sub link 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 2</a></li>
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 3</a>
    <ul class="accordionContent">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">sub link 1</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">sub link 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 4</a></li>
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 5</a></li>
<li><a class="accordionButton" href="javascript:void(0);">head link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.accordionContent').hide();

$('.accordionButton').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).next('.accordionContent').stop().slideToggle("normal");

}, function () {

    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).next('.accordionContent').stop().slideToggle('fast');

}).mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).next('.accordionContent').stop().slideToggle("normal");

}, function () {

    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(this).next('.accordionContent').stop().slideToggle('fast');

});
```

});

Comment: What happens if you put the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` on the containing `<li>`?

Comment: Dan - does that mean swapping out $('.accordionButton').mouseenter(function () to 
$('#mainNav li').mouseenter(function ()? If so, that did not yield any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faGMR/19/)?

```
$(function () {
    var $accContents = $('.accordionContent'),
        $accButtons = $('.accordionButton');

    $accContents.hide();

    $accButtons.on('mouseenter click', function() {
        var $thisContent = $(this).parent().find('.accordionContent');
        if($thisContent.length) {
            $accContents.not($thisContent).slideUp('fast');
            $thisContent.slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Use `.slideDown('fast')` instead of `slideToggle` if no toggle is needed (which would make the click obsolete).